# Numpy: решение системы линейных уравнений методом Гаусса

Tags: python, математика, numpy

Пытаюсь в Python создать алгоритм расчета СЛАУ методом Гаусса. Метод заключается в следующем. Составляем матрицу коэффициентов, включая свободный член. Затем приводим матрицу к треугольному виду. Для этого сначала по первому столбцу (с индексом 0) каждый элемент делим на диагональный (a0,0) (в примере - 3,8), вычисляя индекс m, а после пересчитываем строку 2 по формуле: каждый ее элемент (без элемента свободного члена из последнего столбца) минус произведение элемента над ним (из нулевой строки) и индекса m для второй строки. Отдельно отработаем со столбцом свободного члена (здесь алгоритм неважен).

Следом аналогичные действия надо проделать для третьей строки элементов (но учитывая, что на первой итерации элементы второй строки преобразованы вышеописанным алгоритмом, а коэффициент m будет считаться по второму столбцу: соответственно делим все его элементы на диагональный элемент из 2-й строки a1,1) (в примере 1,3).
Вопрос: я рассчитал вектор-столбец m: m = ([1,000,
1,684,
0,632])

И теперь надо отработать со второй строкой матрицы. И вот здесь сложность с индексацией. Во-первых, не могу перебрать значения m, тип которых float. Во-вторых, неверно задаю индексацию элементов второй строки (по сути — после нулевой это первая строка)

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[3.8, 6.7, -1.2, 5.2], 
                   [6.4, 1.3, -2.7, 3.8], 
                   [2.4, -4.5, 3.5, -0.6]])
def gaussFunc(matrix):
    # расчет len1 (3) и len2 (4) - здесь не приводится
    # код расчета m по нулевому столбцу:
    for row in range(len1):
        for column in range(len2-3):
            m = matrix[row][column] / matrix[column][column]
    elem = row-1                # значения столбцов по нулевой строке кладем в   
                                # переменную elem 
    for i in range(len(m)-1):   # идем циклом по диапазону трех значений m минус 
                                  #последнее третье: ошибка по len для float
                                 
        while row < (len1-1):   # пока строка первая или вторая (в len2 их всего 
                                  # 3):
             while column < (len2-1):  # пока колонка первая, вторая или третья 
                                           # (минус столбец свободного 
                                         # члена):
                 # пересчитанные коэффициенты второй (первой в numpy) строки:
                 # текущий элемент - m по данной строке*верхний элемент в данном 
                 # столбце (из строки 0):
                 a = matrix[row][column] - m[i]*matrix[elem][column]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В конце приведена ссылка на jupyter notebook с более-менее полным решателем СЛАУ. Плюс трюк, как считать на pyton почти так же быстро, как на Фортране :)

---

*Первоначальный ответ*

Если не обращать внимание на возможное деление на ноль, то привидение к треугольному виду можно записать очень просто:

```
def gaussFunc(matrix):
    # функция меняет матрицу через побочные эффекты
    # если вам нужно сохранить прежнюю матрицу, скопируйте её np.copy
    for nrow, row in enumerate(matrix):
        # nrow равен номеру строки
        # row содержит саму строку матрицы
        divider = row[nrow] # диагональный элемент
        # делим на диагональный элемент.
        row /= divider
        # теперь надо вычесть приведённую строку из всех нижележащих строчек
        for lower_row in matrix[nrow+1:]:
            factor = lower_row[nrow] # элемент строки в колонке nrow
            lower_row -= factor*row # вычитаем, чтобы получить ноль в колонке nrow
    # все строки матрицы изменились, в принципе, можно и не возвращать
    return matrix
```

Результат для вашего примера:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  1.76315789, -0.31578947,  1.36842105],
       [-0.        ,  1.        ,  0.06800211,  0.49657354],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.09309401]])
```

В чём засада. В ходе вычислений может оказаться ноль на диагонали.

```
matrix = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], 
                   [0, 0, 1, 2], 
                   [0, 1, 0, 3]])
```

Насколько я помню, перед тем, как делить на диагональный элемент сначала просматривают все строки, начиная с текущей, вниз. Выбирают строку с максимальным значением в текущей колонке и переставляют с текущей. После чего продолжают.

Проверка результата.

Функция `make_identity` берёт матрицу, полученную методом Гаусса, и доводит её до единичной. Для этого строки перебираются снизу вверх и вычитаются из вышележащих строк, чтобы обнулить соответствующие колонки.

```
def make_identity(matrix):
    # перебор строк в обратном порядке 
    for nrow in range(len(matrix)-1,0,-1):
        row = matrix[nrow]
        for upper_row in matrix[:nrow]:
            factor = upper_row[nrow]
            upper_row -= factor*row
    return matrix
```

Результат для вашего примера:`make_identity(gaussFunc(np.copy(matrix)))`

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.53344344],
       [-0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.49024295],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.09309401]])
```

Вырезаем последний столбец, получим строку корней: `roots = make_identity(gaussFunc(np.copy(matrix)))[:,3]`

```
array([0.53344344, 0.49024295, 0.09309401])
```

Умножаем найденные корни на исходную матрицу и сравниваем с последним столбцом исходной задачи: `np.matmul(matrix[:,:3], roots.T) - matrix[:,3]`

Результат вычисления `array([ 0.00000000e+00, -4.44089210e-16, -2.22044605e-16])`

Следовательно, корни найдены правильно. С чем и поздравляю.

**UPDATE**

Метод Гаусса с выбором главного элемента. Плюс добавлена обработка нуля на диагонали.

```
def gaussPivotFunc(matrix):
    for nrow in range(len(matrix)):
        # nrow равен номеру строки
        # np.argmax возвращает номер строки с максимальным элементом в уменьшенной матрице
        # которая начинается со строки nrow. Поэтому нужно прибавить nrow к результату
        pivot = nrow + np.argmax(abs(matrix[nrow:, nrow]))
        if pivot != nrow:
            # swap
            # matrix[nrow], matrix[pivot] = matrix[pivot], matrix[nrow] - не работает.
            # нужно переставлять строки именно так, как написано ниже
            matrix[[nrow, pivot]] = matrix[[pivot, nrow]]
        row = matrix[nrow]
        divider = row[nrow] # диагональный элемент
        if abs(divider) < 1e-10:
            # почти нуль на диагонали. Продолжать не имеет смысла, результат счёта неустойчив
            raise ValueError(f"Матрица несовместна. Максимальный элемент в столбце {nrow}: {divider:.3g}")
        # делим на диагональный элемент.
        row /= divider
        # теперь надо вычесть приведённую строку из всех нижележащих строчек
        for lower_row in matrix[nrow+1:]:
            factor = lower_row[nrow] # элемент строки в колонке nrow
            lower_row -= factor*row # вычитаем, чтобы получить ноль в колонке nrow
    # приводим к диагональному виду
    make_identity(matrix)
    return matrix
```

В этой функции главный фокус в том, как переставлять строки. Простая формула `matrix[nrow], matrix[pivot] = matrix[pivot], matrix[nrow]` не работает. При таком присваивании справа стоят указатели на строку, а слева - адреса, куда нужно **скопировать** значения. То есть при первом присваивании в строку `nrow` будет скопирована строка `pivot`, а в строку `pivot` - содержимое строки `nrow` -- но оно уже переписано из строки `pivot`! То есть фактически строка `pivot` скопируется в саму себя. И вместо перестановки двух строк будет копия одной строки.

`matrix[[nrow, pivot]] = matrix[[pivot, nrow]]` - работает. И c явным копированием тоже работает: `matrix[nrow], matrix[pivot] = matrix[pivot], np.copy(matrix[nrow])`

**UPDATE 2**

[Jupyter Notebook с кодом решателя СЛАУ](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1271321/gauss.ipynb)

Помимо собственно решателя дано сравнение с Си-шным решателем [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) и трюк как ускорить скорость счёта решателя на пайтоне в 20 раз, что почти так же быстро, как чисто Си-шный решатель.

*Строго говоря, решатель в `numpy` даже не Си-шный, а фортрановский [LAPACK gesv](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/db8/group__real_g_esolve_ga3b05fb3999b3d7351cb3101a1fd28e78.html#ga3b05fb3999b3d7351cb3101a1fd28e78)*

Answer (score -1):

Пытаюсь просмотреть и переставить строки - что не так?

```
def gaussFunc(matrix):
    for nrow, row in enumerate(matrix):
    
        max_elem = abs(row[nrow])
        max_row = nrow
        for i in range(nrow + 1, len(matrix)):
            if abs(matrix[i][nrow]) > abs(max_elem):
                max_elem = matrix[i][nrow]
                max_row = i  # фиксируем строку
        if max_row != nrow:
            matrix[nrow], matrix[max_row] = matrix[max_row], matrix[nrow]
```

Comment: я добавил алгоритм с выбором главного элемента в свой ответ. У вас алгоритм выбора главного элемента сделан верно, проблема в перестановке строк. Я добавил объяснение, почему ваше присваивание не работает, в свой ответ. В `numpy` данные при присваивании перезаписываются, поэтому надо либо использовать индексный массив, как в моём решении, либо явным образом копировать данные: `matrix[r1], matrix[r2] = np.copy(matrix[r2]), np.copy(matrix[r1])`

Comment: Благодарю - Вы действительно написали исчерпывающий ответ. Он несет достаточно ценную информацию и полезен не только для решения методом Гаусса, но и для понимания некоторых особенностей numpy